# Removing element after fading out

Tags: jquery

I have some code that does a 90's style mouse trail by appending an image at the cursor coordinates and then fading out. At the moment it keeps the appended image on the page but I want to remove it after it has faded out any clues on what to populate in the callback after fadeOut

Of the few options I have tried it seemed to not show the trail as it was removing too early or by removing all of the

```
(document).mousemove(function(e) {

    pointer = $('<img>').attr({
        'src':'images/sparkle.png'
    });

    $('body').append(pointer);

    pointer.attr('class','pointer').css({
        position:'absolute',
        top: e.pageY +2 ,
        left: e.pageX +2

    }).fadeOut(2000,'easeInOutBounce',function(){
         //something here to remover
    });


});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the `fadeOut` complete callback function you can just put this:

```
$(this).remove();
```

or more optimally, avoiding the jQuery call:

```
this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
```

Also, don't forget the `var` specifier on the declaration of `pointer`, that being the original cause of your problem, because you only had one global `pointer` variable.

That said, it's perfectly possible to write this function without any temporary variables:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    $('<img>', {
       'src': 'images/sparkle.png',
       'class': 'pointer'
    })
    .css({
        top: e.pageY + 2,
        left: e.pageX + 2
    })
    .appendTo(document.body)
    .fadeoOut(2000, 'easeInOutBounce', function() {
         this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
    });
});
```

I've removed the `absolute` and `position` CSS attributes on the element, they'd be better off attached to the `.pointer` class in your CSS style sheet.

Answer (score 1):

It should just be `pointer.remove()`, but you need to locally scope each sparkle. At the moment they share a single global var called `pointer` as you have not declared it local (i.e. with `var`).

e.g.

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    var pointer = $('<img>').attr({
        'src':'images/sparkle.png'
    });

    $('body').append(pointer);

    pointer.attr('class','pointer').css({
        position:'absolute',
        top: e.pageY +2 ,
        left: e.pageX +2

    }).fadeOut(2000,'easeInOutBounce',function(){
         //something here to remover
         pointer.remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thats what I would have thought but this just keeps all of the elements there with display:none;

Comment: @Shane Jones: Also change it to `var pointer = ` so you have a locally scoped variable. Can you provide a JSFiddle or snippet?

Comment: there's actually no need to refer to `pointer` inside the callback - the animated img is in `this`

Comment: @Alnitak: Yes I see that, and yours is optimal, but this does explain the cause and fixes *the original code*. Now please take your 3 up-votes and go away :)

Comment: My point was that using `$(this)` instead of `pointer` makes moot the fact the OP inadvertently failed to declare `pointer` as local ;-)

Comment: @Alnitak: Oh, I get that. I would have up-voted you myself, except you were not clear on the original cause of the problem (and you appear to have enough followers already) :P